# Ethers JS BigNumber Errors

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, bignumber

I'm trying to pass the following number to the `approve()` function of a standard `ERC20` Token contract:

```
2^256-1
```

I read that this should be done using `BigNumber`, using the following code:

```
const maxInt = new BN("2").pow(new BN("256").sub(new BN("1"))); 
// Will pass into solidity as uint 2**256 - 1
```

Well I've gotten **ALL SORTS** of errors using that code - for starters it looks like the syntax and commands for `BigNumber` are quite different depending on the version of `ethers` you happen to be using - and I happen to be on V. 4.0 - and would very much prefer to stay on it right now to avoid other potential headaches.

So I've tried all sorts of variations on the above code - here's one where I broke down each component of that formula into it's own individual piece - just to see what's up:

```
// ==>Using 'bigNumberify'

let bigNum2 = ethers.utils.bigNumberify("2");
console.log("'bigNum2'  -> '2' = ", bigNum2);

let bigNum256 = ethers.utils.bigNumberify("256");
console.log("'bigNum256'  -> '256' = ", bigNum256);

let bigNum2power256 = ethers.utils.bigNumberify(bigNum2.pow(bigNum256));
console.log("'bigNum2power256'  -> 2^256= ", bigNum2power256);

let bigNum1 = ethers.utils.bigNumberify("1");
console.log("'bigNum1'  -> '1' = ", bigNum1);

let finalNumber = ethers.utils.bigNumberify(bigNum2power256 - bigNum1);
console.log("'finalNumber' = ", finalNumber);
```

Well when I pass this `finalNumber` into `approve()` I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: underflow (operation="setValue", fault="underflow", value=1.157920892373162e+77, outputValue=1, version=4.0.45)
```

I've tried all sorts of variations on this code - like replacing this line:

```
let bigNum2power256 = ethers.utils.bigNumberify(bigNum2.pow(bigNum256));
```

with:

```
let bigNum2power256 = bigNum1.pow(bigNum2);
```

but that doesn't work either.

Every variation I tried - and there've been lots - seems to give me yet another sort of error - why is this is difficult?
What's the right way to do this?

=========================

**UPDATE:**

To be clear, the value of `2^256-1` - which I'm storing in my `bigNum2power256` variable, ultimately needs to be passed-in as the 2nd argument of the following contract function call:

```
tokenContractInstance.approve(contractAddress, bigNum2power256, { gasLimit: 500_000 }).then((txResult) => {
    console.log("Back from 'tokenContractInstance' 'approve'");
    console.log(">Here's the 'approve' txResult = \n", txResult);
     .....
}
```

Comment: You can just import `MaxUint256` from `@ethersproject/constants`

Comment: OK I looked into this - and I'm not sure I follow. (I've made a small update to my original question - please have a look at the bottom.) But this `@ethersproject/constants` seems like a node module for `Solidity`, not for Javascript. (I think.) So I don't understand how exactly I'm supposed to import it into my JS code, or how I'm supposed to then use this `MaxUint256` in my JS code. Please look at the update. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg  Can you please elaborate on your previous comment? I have no idea what I'm supposed to be doing with this `@ethersproject/constants` or `MaxUint256` - and how to use them in my *javascript* code to pass the value of 2^256-1 into my smart-contract

Comment: can you try it with smaller values. That might be a bug if your are using v5

Comment: @Mark55 you might need to take a Node.js development course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ethers.js, there is a constants module you can use directly: [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/constants/#constants-MaxUint256)

```
const maxNumber = ethers.constants.MaxUint256
```